# What is "linear projection" in convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, deep-residual-networks

I am reading through [Residual learning](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/He_Deep_Residual_Learning_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf), and I have a question.
What is "linear projection" mentioned in 3.2? Looks pretty simple once got this but could not get the idea...

Can someone provide simple example?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First up, it's important to understand what `x`, `y` and `F` are and why they need any projection at all. I'll try explain in simple terms, but basic understanding of [ConvNets](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) is required.

`x` is an input data (called *tensor*) of the layer, in case of ConvNets it's rank is 4. You can think of it as a [4-dimensional array](https://blog.digilentinc.com/arrays-theyre-not-so-scary/). `F` is usually a conv layer (`conv+relu+batchnorm` in this paper), and `y` combines the two together (forming the output channel). The result of `F` is also of rank 4, and most of dimensions will be the same as in `x`, except for one. That's exactly what the transformation should patch.

For example, `x` shape might be `(64, 32, 32, 3)`, where 64 is the batch size, 32x32 is image size and 3 stands for (R, G, B) color channels. `F(x)` might be `(64, 32, 32, 16)`: batch size never changes, for simplicity, ResNet conv-layer doesn't change the image size too, but will likely use a different number of filters - 16.

So, in order for `y=F(x)+x` to be a valid operation, `x` must be "reshaped" from `(64, 32, 32, 3)` to `(64, 32, 32, 16)`.

**I'd like to stress here that "reshaping" here is not what `numpy.reshape` does.**

Instead, `x[3]` is padded with 13 zeros, like this:

```
pad(x=[1, 2, 3],padding=[7, 6]) = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you think about it, this is a projection of a 3-dimensional vector onto 16 dimensions. In other words, we start to think that our vector is the same, but there are 13 more dimensions out there. None of the other `x` dimensions are changed.

Here's [the link](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/layers/conv.py#L1491) to the code in Tensorflow that does this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have mainly used matlab rather than python, and there might be a misunderstanding I guess. 
In matlab the last dimension is # of image
in python the first dimension is # of image.

Comment: Got you. The order may be different, but the projection should be done like described in the answer.

Comment: Please disregard above one.

Comment: Ah... again... habitually punched enter. The below is my actual question:

Thank you very much, but I still have questions. I blame my clumsiness.

My first questions is about width and height reduction in a residual connection. For example, they used stride of 2 which will lead to width and height reduction rather than number of filters. This was my first question.

After I got your lessons, I realized different number of channels also cause problem.

Could you provide me another lesson about them?. I mean different (width and height), and (different channel) in residual connection?

Comment: Good question, but not enough space here to fully answer it. In short: when the layer downsamples the image (by using `strides=2`), `x` goes through a pooling layer **as well** with same stride. So both `F(x)` and `x` reduce the size of an image by half, and just like before only the "channel" dimension needs to be projected. I could only find an example in python: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/residual_network_mnist.py You can see two layers with `downsample=True`, both of which scale down the image.

Comment: The link to tensorflow code wasn't anchored to a specific commit so I believe it is now pointing to the wrong line of code as a result of changes on the master branch

Answer (score 1):

A linear projection is one where each new feature is simple a weighted sum of the original features. As in the paper, this can be represented by matrix multiplication. if `x` is the vector of `N` input features and `W` is an `M`-by`N` matrix, then the matrix product `Wx` yields `M` new features where each one is a linear projection of `x`. Each row of `W` is a set of weights that defines one of the `M` linear projections (i.e., each row of `W` contains the coefficients for one of the weighted sums of `x`).

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanations. Please confirm if I correctly understand. If an input x has 3X3 and we want to project it to 4X4. Than, we vectorize x[3X3] to [9X1]. and the W will be [16X9]. Therefore, the W [16X9] x [9X1] = [16X1], and reshape it to [4X4]. Is this what you explained?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: @W.Choi this answer is technically correct, but a bit misleading, as can be seen by your comment. Please see my answer.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the author went with zero padding, instead of "stretching" the values, for example [1 2 3] stretching to [? ? ? ? ? ?] where it could be [0.5 0.5 1 1 1.5 1.5]. Zero padding means the original tensor affects only couple of the output tensor

Answer (score 1):

In Pytorch (in particular torchvision\models\resnet.py), at the end of a Bottleneck you will either have two scenarios

1. The input vector x's channels, say x_c (not spatial resolution, but channels), are less than equal to the output after layer conv3 of the Bottleneck, say d dimensions. This can then be alleviated by a 1 by 1 convolution with in planes = x_c and out_planes = d, with stride 1, followed by batch normalization, and then the addition F(x) + x occurs assuming x and F(x) have the same spatial resolution.
2. Both the spatial resolution of x and its number of channels don't match the output of the BottleNeck layer, in which case the 1 by 1 convolution mentioned above needs to have stride 2 in order for both the spatial resolution and the number of channels to match for the element-wise addition (again with batch normalization of x before the addition).